# $T^*$ is invertible whenever $T$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Is the following argument correct? In addition can someone please provide some insight concerning the second claim in the given proposition.

> **Proposition**. Let $V$ be finite-dimensional inner product space, and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Prove that if $T$ is
>   invertible then $T^*$ is invertible and $(T^*)^{-1} = (T^{-1})^*$.

*Proof.*  Assume $T$ is invertible and $T^*w_0 = 0$ where $w_0\in V$ then by definition of adjoint $\langle Tv,w_0\rangle = 0,\forall v\in V$, but from hypothesis there exists a $v_0\in V$ such that $Tv_0 = w_0$ consequently $\langle Tv_0,w_0\rangle = \langle w_0,w_0\rangle = 0$ implying $w_0 = 0$. 
Thus $\operatorname{null}T^* = \{0\}$ equivalently $T^*$ is injective and by theorem $\textbf{2.5}$ invertible.

$\blacksquare$

---

**Note:** $\textbf{2.5}$ is the result that given an operator $T$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ invertibility,injectivity and surjectivity are all equivalent.

Comment: Yes, that works. To prove $(T^*)^{-1}=(T^{-1})^*$, use the same idea. Let's show that $T^*(T^{-1})^*v-v=0$. For all $w\in V$, $\langle T^*(T^{-1})^*v-v,w\rangle=\langle T^*(T^{-1})^*v,w\rangle-\langle v,w\rangle=\langle v,T^{-1}Tw\rangle-\langle v,w\rangle=0$. Therefore, $T^*(T^{-1})^*v-v=0$. This means that $(T^{-1})^*=(T^*)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Now, let $u\in V$. Since $T$ is surjective, $u=Tw$ for some vector $w$. If $v\in V$,$$\bigl\langle(T^{-1})^*v,Tw\bigr\rangle=\bigl\langle v,T^{-1}Tw\bigr\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$$and$$\bigl\langle(T^*)^{-1}v,Tw\bigr\rangle=\bigl\langle T^*(T^*)^{-1}v,w\bigr\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle.$$Since $(\forall u,v\in V):\bigl\langle(T^{-1})^*v,u\bigr\rangle=\bigl\langle(T^*)^{-1}v,u\bigr\rangle$, you have $(T^{-1})^*=(T^*)^{-1}$.

Comment: Alternatively, once you establish $(ST)^* = T^* S^*$, it follows that $$T^* (T^{-1})^* = (T^{-1}T)^* = I^* = I,$$ and similarly for $(T^{-1})^* T^* = I$. This shows, by definition, $(T^{-1})^*$ is the inverse of $T^*$.

Comment: I knew there was a shorter proof! (I'm serious.)

Comment: To prove $(ST)^*=T^*S^*$ you need to do the same amount of computation, plus then applying it to $TT^{-1}=I$ and show that $I^*=I$. It is not really shorter. It is, at best, the same.

Comment: @LB_O Nice point!